# serving .dart-files from lib/-folder

Tags: dart, dart-pub

This is my (simplified) folder structure:

```
/
  pubspec.yaml
  build/
    client.dart.js, etc
  lib/
    game.dart
  server/
    server.dart
  web/
    client.dart
    canvas.dart
    index.html
```

I'm using the code from the "dartiverse search"-sample for serving these files (simplified):

```dart
var buildDirectory = new Http.VirtualDirectory(buildPath);
buildDirectory.jailRoot = false;

// Serve everything not routed elsewhere through the virtual directory.
buildDirectory.serve(router.defaultStream);

// Special handling of client.dart. Running 'pub build' generates
// JavaScript files but does not copy the Dart files, which are
// needed for the Dartium browser.
router.serve("/client.dart").listen((request) {
  Uri clientScript = Platform.script.resolve("../web/client.dart");
  buildDirectory.serveFile(new File(clientScript.toFilePath()), request);
});

router.serve("/canvas.dart").listen((request) {
  Uri clientScript = Platform.script.resolve("../web/canvas.dart");
  buildDirectory.serveFile(new File(clientScript.toFilePath()), request);
});

router.serve("/lib/game.dart").listen((request) {
  Uri clientScript = Platform.script.resolve("../lib/game.dart");
  buildDirectory.serveFile(new File(clientScript.toFilePath()), request);
});
```

My question is: is there a better way to serve files in a project with .dart-files split across lib/ and web/-folders? The method shown above may work fine for a few files, but what if my project grows and I have 50 such .dart-files?

Answer (score 1):

I usually point my VirtualDirectory to web/ so you don't need to map the paths for your files in web/.

For the files in lib/ the Dart Editor(Pub) creates a symlink packages in web/ which points to the packages directory in your project. That packages directory also contains the contents of lib/ so you can access game.dart with /packages//game.dart relative to web/.
The package imports in your dart code will also use this path to fetch the source.

Now all your files will be served by the VirtualDirectory and you only need the router for stuff like websockets etc.

Comment: This seemed like the perfect solution at first, but what about .dart.js-files? They're inside the build/ folder... :/

Comment: For testing with the compiled .dart.js files you can point the VirtualDirectory to build/web/.

Comment: But I want to be able to use both .dart and .dart.js-files at the same time! :)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by use both at the same time? i dont think it makes any sense since the .dart and the .dart.js files contain the same logic just in different formats.

Comment: I want to publish the web app, but most browsers don't support Dart at the moment. I want unsupported browsers to seamlessly use the compiled JavaScript version instead. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: ok that makes total sense. I think since dart2js compiles all your dart files into one big .dart.js file, you only need to copy that into your web/ directory where the dart sources are. The <script src="/packages/browser/dart.js"></script> makes sure to load the javascript only if the browser does not support dart so it should be fine. I run a quick test on one of my projects and it worked fine that way.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I'm at home, but as far as I remember the compiler creates a distinct .dart.js-file for every .dart-file? Thanks for your help in any case!